# Issues using openid-selector/ dotnet openid

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, openid, dotnetopenauth, openid-selector

I'm using openid-selector based UI to authenticate user using dotnet openid API.
I'm having a small issue, when i select google and cancel and close browser and then open link and select yahoo it redirects me google but not yahoo.

i checked that when i click button at bottom on browser status bar it shows correct parameter being sent to singing function in JS file but it somehow takes previous selected value and redirects to that page.

Did somebody same face this issue or can someone help me with an idea or suggestion

Comment: When you "close browser and then open link" what link are you opening?  I don't understand.  Also, are you using any of the built-in ASP.NET controls are going the pure programmatic route?  Which openid-selector are you using?  (there are several)

Comment: WHen i open Logon page it uses old selection value

I'm using http://code.google.com/p/openid-selector/
Even in the example demo files it uses previous selection value on login page..

I'm using it in ASP.NET MVC app

Answer (score 1):

This is openid-selector Javascript bug.
You should download openid-selector v1.1 or v1.2